# How to merge or combine the results in mvc4 to get the desired result

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I have done an application in `asp.net` which works fine, now I am converting the same application to `MVC` as I am new to `MVC` I got struck at a point, i.e I would like bind three different results to the same `view`. The one which I done in `asp.net` is as follows

[image]

The same result I would like to display in `MVC` view I have done it partially and I got the result as follows but I got strucked for the remaining two

[image]

This is my code to display the first result, and I will have a stored procedure in my model to bind the Stats result as per shown in first Image,

```
@model IEnumerable<forumAPP.tblTechnology>
<tr class="row1">
<td class="altrow">
</td>
<td>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TechName)
<br />
<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TechDesc)
<br />
<br />
<hr style="-moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none; border-color: #EBEBEB; border-image: none; border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; display: block; width: 105%;" />
}
</td>
```

So can some one help me how can I display multiple results on the same view

Answer (score 0):

Look into `ViewModels`. You can easily combine related data and then pass a collection of those `ViewModels` to the View and handle it appropriately.

I highly recommend the ASP.NET MVC tutorials for first time MVC programmers, even if you're very proficient at LINQ, C#, ASP.NET, etc. You can find them at: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials